# DART string constant set to timestamp as at compilation

Tags: dart

How can I get a string constant automatically set to the datestamp as at **compile** time?

Something like:

```
    const String COMPILE_DATESTAMP = eval_static(DateTime.now().toString());
    ...
    String s = "This program was compiled $COMPILE_DATESTAMP";
```

where s would then be for e.g.
"This program was compiled 1971-02-03 04:05:06"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question!

There's no required compile step in Dart. (We do have an optional Dart-to-JavaScript compiler, or even a Dart-to-Dart processor that does tree shaking.) Dart's VM accepts input as text files. Similar to Ruby or Python, it runs text-based scripts.

As others have mentioned, this is a job for some sort of build step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Dart, but I haven't seen anything in the documentation to suggest that such a thing is possible.  I strongly suspect that it isn't.

If you really need functionality like you describe, I think your best bet is to roll your own build script.  Something simple like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sed -ri "s/INSERT_DATETIME_HERE/`date`/" $1
dart2js $1 -o$1.js
```

could be modified to suit your needs.  (I'd want some sanity checks in there if it were me; I'm just suggesting a starting point.)  Your code would become:

```java
const String COMPILE_DATESTAMP = "INSERT_DATETIME_HERE";
...
String s = "This program was compiled $COMPILE_DATESTAMP";
```

Comment: Nice... but platform specific, and adds a manual process to the build.  The idea is a 100% reliable indication tot he user of the version of the software.

Comment: Sure, a shell script is limited to UNIXy environments.  My point was that Dart does not have anything like your `eval_static`, but it's trivial to write a build script in whatever language you like to accomplish what you want.  It's automatic, not manual; you're doing exactly one step, just as you would if you used `dart2js` directly.  If the issue is that you're using an IDE, I'd be surprised if you couldn't configure your IDE to use a script of yours during the build process.  Whatever your build process is, I'm merely suggesting scripting it to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You must write another [[image]dart](/questions/tagged/dart) program that could examine the actual compiled program. Then is simple as:

```
File compiledApp = new File('path/to/compiled/app.dart');
compiledApp.lastModified().then(
   (modifiedDate)
   {
        print("This program was compiled $modifiedDate");
   },
   onError: (exp) 
            {
               // File doesn't exist ?
            }
   );
```

This trick build on knowledge that compiler will modify the 'last modify date' of the file